# How do I list all masterpages using client object model

Tags: client-object-model, master-page

I want to get all masterpages in client object model.
For classic lists and libraries, I use

```
context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listname)
```

How do I do that to get the masterpage list (_catalogs/masterpage) ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Title of the list is "Master Page Gallery". Remember that, that lists also contains things other than the master pages. For example, Page Layouts, images for the page layouts etc.

The link below shows how to filter master pages:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716074/retrieve-all-master-pages-for-a-sharepoint-site

Comment: Thanks, it works. For other reasons, I ended up doing context.Web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl("_catalogs/masterpage"). Mainly because I'd rather have a Folder object.

Answer (score 3):

Another good way of getting a SharePoint Catalog is:

```
var value = SP.Site.getCatalog(116);
```

As described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ee659560.aspx) ([TypeCatalog enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splisttemplatetype.aspx))

Answer (score 1):

In the root web context, try:

> context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Master Page Gallery")